# Mongoose near(...) query on 2dsphere indexed field not returning valid results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am unable to query a mongodb database using mongoose's `qry.where().near()` syntax.

I have a Schema with coordinates stored as an array, indexed as `2dsphere`:

```
loc : { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere' }
```

I am running a mongoose query using `.where().near()`:

```
qry.where('loc').near({
    center: search.loc,
    maxDistance: search.distance * 1000
});
```

I have enabled `mongoose.set('debug', true)`, and can see the resulting debug:

#### Inserting 2 documents in the collection with coordinates `[ 10, -20 ]`:

```
Mongoose: models.insert({ _id: ..., loc: [ 10, -20 ], type: 'apple' }) {}  
Mongoose: models.insert({ _id: ..., loc: [ 10, -20 ], type: 'orange' }) {}
```

#### Searching for documents near coordinates `[ 10, -20 ]`:

```
Mongoose: models.find({ loc: { '$near': [ 10, -20 ], '$maxDistance': 1000 } })
```

*The query returns **no results.***

I have proved the documents are in the database by searching on `type`. Its the geospatial query I can't get to work.

I am using `mongodb v2.6.1` and `mongoose v3.8.8`

### Full working example below:

#### Schema: (model.js)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ModelSchema = new Schema({
    type : { type: String, index: true },
    loc  : { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere' }
});

ModelSchema.index({type: 1, loc: 1});

ModelSchema.statics.search = function(search, cb) {
    var qry = this.find();
    if (search.types) {
        qry.where('type').in(search.types);
    }
    if (search.loc) {
        qry.where('loc').near({
            center: search.loc,
            maxDistance: search.distance * 1000
        });
    }
    qry.exec(cb);
};
```

#### Mocha test: (test.ts)

```
var q = require('node-promise'),
    should = require('should'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my-test');
var Model = require('./model');

describe('My Model', function() {
    before(function(done) {
        mongoose.set('debug', true);

        Model.remove().exec(function() {
            var create = function(promises, body) {
                var p = new q.Promise();
                var m = new Model(body);
                m.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        p.reject();
                    } else {
                        p.resolve();
                    }
                });
                promises.push(p);
            };

            var promises = [];
            create(promises, { type: 'apple',  loc: [ 10, -20 ] });
            create(promises, { type: 'orange', loc: [ 10, -20 ] });
            create(promises, { type: 'apple',  loc: [ 15,  10 ] });
            create(promises, { type: 'orange', loc: [ 15,  10 ] });
            q.all(promises).then(function() {
                done();
            })
        });
    });

    it('should find all', function(done) {
        Model.search({}, function(err, items) {
            items.should.have.length(4);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('should find apples', function(done) {
        Model.search({types: ['apple']}, function(err, items) {
            items.should.have.length(2);
            done();
        });
    });

    // this test fails
    it('should find coords', function(done) {
        Model.search({loc: [ 10, -20 ], distance: 1}, function(err, items) {
            items.should.have.length(2);
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

#### package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "~3.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "should": "~2.1.0",
    "node-promise": "0.5.10"
  }
}
```

#### Run through mocha:

```
sudo npm install -g mocha
npm install
mocha ./test.js
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seems this is a **moongoose bug**.

Changing the query to **use a `GeoJSON` object instead of a coordinate pair**, as such:

```
qry.where('loc').near({
    center: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: search.loc
    },
    maxDistance: search.distance * 1000
});
```

results in the following query:

```
Mongoose: models.find({ loc: { '$near': { 
        '$maxDistance': 1,
        '$geometry': { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 10, -20 ] } } } 
    }) { fields: undefined }
```

**The search now succeeds.**

The [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-near) explicitly show a query using a coordinate pair:

```
query.where('loc').near({ center: [10, 10], maxDistance: 5 });
```

However, it looks like this doesn't work, and the example should be:

```
query.where('loc').near({ center: { coordinates: [10, 10], type: 'Point' }, maxDistance: 5 });
```

Comment: If your index is a 2dsphere you must use GeoJSON notation, if it's just 2d you need to use a coordinate pair.

Comment: you, @Steve, are  life saver!

Comment: How can I show the exact distance? Example: user.distance = 2230 meters. Is possible to order by proximity?

Comment: @IgorMartins did you find the answer for that?