# Mongoose geo query does not return correct result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation

I am trying to query a database where i am storing coordinates for location near certain coordinates and also specifying a maxDistance.
I read on the official mongo documentation that the maxDistance in in meters.
the collection schema is as follows:

```
var BranchSchema = new Schema({
parentId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: 'The ID of the parent is required.',
    index: true
},
name: {
    type: 'String',
    required: 'The branch name is required.'
},
location: {
    type: [Number],
    index: {
        type: '2dsphere'
    }
}
});
```

i had inserted a document that has the following information:

```
{
"parentId" : ObjectId("54ee08c2d903aca72291f120"),
"name" : "Branch1",
"_id" : ObjectId("54ee422809f242122744990c"),
"location" : [ 
    33.377796, 
    35.480911
]
}
```

i then try to query for lat=33.901948 and long=35.576797 with a max distance 5.
i used an online tool on the web (http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) that gives the distance between lat=33.901948 and long=35.576797 and lat=33.377796 and long=35.480911 as 58KM, obviously greater than 5 meters and still the query return the result while it shouldn't

the mongoose query is as follows:

```
 Branch.where('location').near({
    center: [lat, long],
    maxDistance: proximity,
    spherical: true
}).exec(function (err, branches) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400)
            .send({
                message: errors.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
    }
    return res.json(branches);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems this is a bug with mongoose, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947157/mongoose-near-query-on-2dsphere-indexed-field-not-returning-valid-results?rq=1

Comment: Please note that center is specified like [long, lat]  not [lat, long]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I've been seeing some mistakes on your issue;

1- Index.

```
 - 2dsphere index if specifying a GeoJSON point
 - 2d index if specifying a point using legacy coordinates.
```

Your schema uses a legacy coordinate field. It's not a GeoJSON field. Because a GeoJSON has to be included a coordinate type value like the following;

```
location: {
            'type': { type: String, default: 'Point' },
             coordinates: [Number]
           }
```

If you want to legacy coordinate field you should use `2d` index.

2- the order of lat. and lng.
  Your codes must [start with `Longitude`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#query-on-geojson-data)

```
IMPORTANT
Specify coordinates in this order: “longitude, latitude.”
```

On the other hand if you wanna use legacy 2d index you might use [the following codes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#query-on-legacy-coordinates);

```
{ location : { $near : [ -73.9667, 40.78 ], $maxDistance: 0.10 } }
```

The above codes hava a `$maxDistance` parameter that specifies the `radius`. I think you should check [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) out. Beacuse you must consider the following line to find 5 meters proximity.

`5 meters = (5 / 6371000) radius of the earth`

So, I think the following codes work;

```
Branch.where('location').near({
    center: [long, lat],
    maxDistance: 5/6371000,
    spherical: true
}).exec(function (err, branches) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400)
            .send({
                message: errors.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
    }
    return res.json(branches);
});
```

Or

```
Branch.find(
    { location : { $near : [ -73.9667, 40.78 ], $maxDistance: 5/6371000 }}, 
    function (err, branches) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400)
            .send({
                message: errors.getErrorMessage(err)
            })
        }
        return res.json(branches);
    }
)
```

I hope this helps, good luck!